# Using Custom Fonts in iOS with Typekit by Adobe

Tags: ios, fonts, typekit

I know its possible to use customs font in an app by thrown a .tff in and changing the info.plist but is it possible to use font from typekit.com ? My client wants a specific font off there called Omnes Pro. but the site seems to be geared towards just HTML devs. which I am none the such. Any help guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with TypeKit but by simply checking their site thoroughly, I found the following link: [Now serving truetype fonts to iOS 4.2 devices](http://blog.typekit.com/2011/01/10/now-serving-truetype-fonts-to-ios-4-2-devices/)

This hints pretty reliably that they do actually offer OpenType and/or TrueType font formatted files after purchase.

Comment: This is really just talking about Safari Mobile. For native apps, or any app that doesn't require the user to have network connectivity, I don't believe it's possible to use Typekit.

Answer (score 12):

TypeKit fonts are for web use only, so this isn't possible

http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/6854-using-fonts-in-desktop-applications

**EDIT**

Looks like TypeKit desktop syncing means fonts are not 'web only' anymore, but their license still doesn't allow embedding in native applications as of February 2014:

From http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/1341590:

**Can I embed Typekit desktop fonts in a mobile or desktop app I’m building?**

No. Neither the Typekit sync font license or web font license allows you to embed the fonts within mobile or desktop apps. Currently, this requires the appropriate license to be purchased directly from the foundry or one of their authorized resellers.

Comment: Read that link carefully. Many TypeKit fonts *are* usable on the desktop. Not sure about iOS (I actually found this question because I am researching TypeKit for use in Android apps), but TypeKit is most definitely not "for web use only".

Comment: The downvote is a little harsh - TypeKit desktop syncing came out in Jan 2014, 8 months after my comment. And my answer is still correct in the context of the question answered - you cannot use Typekit within a native app

Comment: Weird - there's a contradiction in that link. See "Can I use Typekit web fonts for anything other than a website?" and "Can I use Typekit desktop fonts to create images?" ("Yes. You can use any Typekit desktop font in any desktop tool (like Adobe Photoshop) to create images, which you can then use for any purpose.")

Comment: IANAL, but I think the distinction is between using the font in artwork you create (by importing it into Photoshop). You can do that, and then print the artwork, say onto a t-shirt. VS embedding the font in a product or application you *ship*. So, Adobe couldn't use a Typekit font in Photoshop for their menu labels. And you can't use a Typekit font in your iOS App. But yeah, it's not obvious at all is it :(