# How can I to use Adobe Fonts in Xcode / iOS App development?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fonts, adobe

How can I use Adobe Fonts in app development. I have an Adobe XD mockup I am trying to build.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Custom Fonts in iOS with Typekit by Adobe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147394/using-custom-fonts-in-ios-with-typekit-by-adobe)